# C# - How to find the custom tag's Name and Text from Html

Tags: c#

I have requirement where I have input Html like this -

```
  <col name="col1">Text1</col>
  <col name="col2">Text2</col>
  <col name="col3">text3</col>
```

Now I have to parse this Html and create a csv file with below output -

```
col1,col2,col3
Text1,Text2,text3
```

Please let me know how can this be achieved in C#.

Comment: This seems like a great little problem that you would really benefit from learning how to achieve on your own. It involves writing parsing rules and then storing the data in a way that will provide simplistic output. You should have a go yourself, it really will benefit your development in C#.

Comment: Thanks ThePower and Grunf for quick reply. Can you please help me with the exact Regular Expression in this case? Other code I can manage..

Comment: Personally think that parsing html with a regex is an awful idea. There exists a bunch of HTML parsers which will do a better job than you'll do with regex 100% of the time.

Comment: Why not use a runat server tag on those fields.  Do you have to parse all the HTML or only the portion above?  If you add a runat server tag then you should be able to get the id and the innerText.

Comment: Is the input really HTML or XML, you example can be XML.  You could use LINQ and XML to process the data.

Comment: The input is HTML which can have this tag, so can not use the XML parser.. I am not worried about the rest of HTML, I just need to retrieve name value and data within the "<col></Col>" tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this regular expression and it worked gr8...

```
<col[\\s]*name=\"?([0-9a-zA-Z ]*)\"?>((.|\n)*?)</col>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Avoid regular expressions [at all cost](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).